# How to solve amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH? Status Blackhole

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, packer

I run my packer build

```
==> amazon-ebs: Terminating the source AWS instance...
==> amazon-ebs: Cleaning up any extra volumes...
==> amazon-ebs: No volumes to clean up, skipping
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary security group...
==> amazon-ebs: Deleting temporary keypair...
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored after 6 minutes 23 seconds: Timeout waiting for SSH.
```

and

```
==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH.
```

I checked my VPC(for user in packer build example)

[image]

How to solve this issue?

I removed the default VPC and created the new one with subnet. Added two lines into json

```
"vpc_id": "vpc-0bb5a477b899e995d",
"subnet_id": "subnet-00934a52461387401",
```

I got again

```
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored after 6 minutes 26 seconds: Timeout waiting for SSH.
```

I checked the route table again
[image]

Comment: From the AWS docs: `The blackhole state indicates that the route's target isn't available (for example, the specified gateway isn't attached to the VPC, or the specified NAT instance has been terminated).`.

Comment: @MarkoE ok,what are the steps to resolve this? I found out I do not have IG,will create one.

Comment: I'd say that is the first step.

Comment: @MarkoE Can you take a look now?

Comment: There are very few details in the question related to setup. For example, is the EC2 instance in a private or a public subnet? If it is in a public subnet, does it have a public IP? If not, how do you plan to SSH into an EC2 instance in a private subnet? Do you have IGW and NAT GW defined for the VPC?

Comment: @MarkoE I do not have IGW and NAT GW seems that is the problem.